# abcde cannot look up CD information

Tags: abcde, musicbrainz

When I try to rip a CD with `abcde` it always returns:

```
MusicBrainz lookup returned an error "Not Found"
```

but when I run `abcde-musicbrainz-tool` it can return discid:

```
2Abo08qbmuoiRQqzbVxAqhBFjBM- 23 150 12781 28999 46084 59816 66151 76276 92595 113027 129557 149900 171945 183322 191990 214045 223417 249454 261333 274261 299227 309980 330897 343322 4732
```

(This is Mahler Des Knaben Wunderhorn album by Charles Mackerras.)

I wonder if there's a way to fix `abcde`'s CD lookup problem, or to input the information given by `abcde-musicbrainz-tool` during ripping?

(Using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Comment: Would you consider using `CDDBMETHOD=cddb` in combination with `CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"` rather than musicbrainz?

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks, this is working for the Mahler CD and another Wagner CD, not for the Bach CD though. But it is quite helpful.

Comment: The current developer of abcde was the one who created the musicbrainz perl script and can be found at #abcde on Libera Chat. He would be happy to look at this issue I am sure. I am also there (retired abcde developer) but musicbrainz is his baby.

Comment: @andrew.46 You should make CDDB+gnudb an answer.  That was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I was one of the abcde developers from 2015-2017...*

It is not always necessary to use `abcde-musicbrainz-tool` for your CDDB lookup needs with abcde. There is an older protocol in place that can be accessed by adding the following to your `~/.abcde.conf` file:

```
CDDBMETHOD=cddb
CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"
```

And this may be all you need to get your CDDB searches going.

To round out this usage a little you would also be wise to also add the following:

```
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"
```

This will make your future searches a little more efficient.

**Caveat:**

Although you should find that abcde works well enough bear in mind that the project is somewhat *somnolent* at the moment and unlikely to receive much more development.